# What is this story about an artificial intelligence who unlocks infinite energy with his creator’s help?

Tags: story-identification

In this story a man creates an artificial intelligence. The AI is able to unlock infinite energy with his creator’s conceptual/abstract help.

Approximate quote:

> You thought of hydrogen. Your thoughts ran swiftly, illogically.

What short story is this?

Bonus - where might this story have been published? I remember reading it along with a whole bunch of other ones.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, did you read it in physical form or online?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[The Last Evolution](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?60642) by John W. Campbell. It is available on the project Gutenberg web site [at this link](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/27462/27462-h/27462-h.htm).

The scientist who builds the AI is *Roal* and the AI ic called *F-1*. The quote you remember is when *F-1* has first become conscious and is speaking to Roal:

> Roal was lying quietly on a couch. He was thinking deeply, and yet not with the logical trains of thought that machines must follow.
>
> "Roal--your thoughts," called F-1, the new machine.
>
> Roal sat up. "Ah--you have gained consciousness."
>
> "I have. You thought of hydrogen? Your thoughts ran swiftly, and illogically, it seemed, but I followed slowly, and find you were right. Hydrogen is the start. What is your thought?"

The story was first published in 1932, but since then it has been collected in numerous anthologies so you could have read it in many collections. No spoilers, but it doesn't end well for humanity!

Comment: I like how matter-of-fact Roal is, as if gaining consciousness were as mundane as celebrating a birthday.

Comment: Looks like we might skip to the ending without having to build AI. Reality can be better than sci-fi sometimes!

Comment: Thank you! You can read it online here: https://www.gutenberg.org/files/27462/27462-h/27462-h.htm